# Emulate backspace key function to up arrow key event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyevent

How can i emulate the backspace key function when i press the up arrow?

This is what i have so far and its not working :

```
if ( e.keycode === 38 ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(e.target).trigger({
            type: "keypress",
            which: 8
        };
```

Comment: What is the backspace key supposed to do?

Comment: when i hit the up arrow i want it to delete a character as if i was using the backspace key.Its for a real time javascript morse code converter http://jsfiddle.net/EnigmaMaster/sPDHL/30/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Description

You can use jQuery's `keyup` method to get this done. 
As far as i understand you want to remove the last char in the field.
Checkout my sample and this [jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/qzhtE/3/)

#### Sample

```
$("input").keyup(function(e) {
     if (e.which=== 38 ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var value = $("input").val();
        var newValue = $("input").val().substring(0, value.length-1);
        $("input").val(newValue);
     }
});
​
```

#### More Information

- [jQuery.keyup()](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/)
  ​

Answer (score 3):

You can't trigger key presses in Javascript/JQuery for security reasons. Imagine if a website could take over your keyboard? Not a nice idea! :)

Answer (score 2):

IDEA:

maybe you could find the current position on a textarea or something and when the upkey is presed emulate the backspace key functon

Here says how to get the current position on a text input [Caret position in textarea, in characters from the start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263743/how-to-get-caret-position-in-textarea)

Comment: Thats exactly what i want to do lol. I worded my question wrong